Dynamically created ACF select field returning false
I am using this which lists all posts from a CPT on site 1, from site 2 (multisite wordpress site).
On site 2, I select the name in the select field and shows as selected after the page has updated, but on the front-end of the site there are no values selected. CAn anyone help me figure this out please?
function populate_speakers_field_from_site_1($field) {
    // Switch to Site 1
    $site_1_id = 1; // Replace with your Site 1 ID
    switch_to_blog($site_1_id);

    // Fetch all speakers
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'speakers',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'asc',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );

    $speakers_query = new WP_Query($args);

    // Reset choices
    $field['choices'] = array();

    // Loop through speakers and add to field choices
    if ($speakers_query->have_posts()) {
        while ($speakers_query->have_posts()) {
            $speakers_query->the_post();
            $field['choices'][get_the_ID()] = get_the_title();
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    // Restore to current blog (Site 2)
    restore_current_blog();

    return $field;
}
add_filter('acf/load_field/key=field_6699142ff52aa', 'populate_speakers_field_from_site_1');

and to retrieve the data I'm just doing a simple var_dump(get_field_object('field_6699142ff52aa'));
C:\wamp64\www\esmedia\wp-content\themes\ES-Live\templates\template-events.php:241:
array (size=26)
  'ID' => int 244
  'key' => string 'field_6699142ff52aa' (length=19)
  'label' => string 'Speakers Names' (length=14)
  'name' => string 'scheduled_speakers' (length=18)
  'aria-label' => string '' (length=0)
  'prefix' => string 'acf' (length=3)
  'type' => string 'select' (length=6)
  'value' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'menu_order' => int 9
  'instructions' => string '' (length=0)
  'required' => int 0
  'id' => string '' (length=0)
  'class' => string '' (length=0)
  'conditional_logic' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
  'parent' => int 150
  'wrapper' => 
    array (size=3)
      'width' => string '' (length=0)
      'class' => string '' (length=0)
      'id' => string '' (length=0)
  'choices' => 
    array (size=179)
      947 => string 'Abigail Barnes' (length=14)
      1163 => string 'Abigail Barnes and Helen Rees' (length=29)
      42137 => string 'Abigail Rudner' (length=14)
      1002 => string 'Adam Hergenrother' (length=17)
      1004 => string 'Adam Hergenrother and Hallie Warner' (length=35)
      41950 => string 'Ali Pasha' (length=9)
      959 => string 'Alice Scutchey' (length=14)
      38242 => string 'Alicia Fairclough' (length=17)
      40584 => string 'Aliina Rowe' (length=11)
      2566 => string 'Amanda Johnson' (length=14)
      1458 => string 'Amy McKeown' (length=11)
      907 => string 'Andrea Macarie' (length=14)

etc etc

947 => string 'Abigail Barnes' is the selected person in the select, but as you can see, the values are empty.
I am wanting the selected people (in this case Abigail Barnes) to be displayed only so I can do a database search with their ID's

Managed to get the value by directly querying the database and getting the meta_key value
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_2_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE '%scheduled_speakers_names%';");
